# merging data from old table into new for a monthly archive

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a sql statement to insert data into a table for archiving, but I need a merge statement to run on a monthyl basis to update the new table(2) with any data that changed in the old table(1) that should now be moved into archive.

Part of the issue is to remove the moved data from the old table.  My insert is not doing that, but I need to have it to where the saved data is purged from the original table.

Is there a single sql statement that will move data out of one table into another in this way?  Or does it need to be a two step operation?

the initial statement moved data depending on age and a few other relative factors.
 insert is:

```
INSERT /*+ append */ 
  INTO tab1
SELECT *
  FROM tab2
 WHERE (Postingdate < TO_DATE ('2001/07/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
       OR jobname IS NULL)
   AND STATUS <> '45';
```

All help appreciated...

Comment: You may be able to accomplish this by exchanging partitions: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_3001.htm#BABHHAHF

Answer (score 0):

The `merge` statement will let you do this in one statement by adding a delete statement in the update clause. See [Oracle Documentation on Merge](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm).

Comment: But both the insert and the delete will only affect the destination table.

Comment: So there would have to be an additional delete statement to remove data from the source table?

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that the delete was for the source table. I don't believe there is a 'one shot' solution to this (unless you count adding a trigger to either table) - you will need to have an equivalent delete statement following the insert. There shouldn't be any data integrity issues if your values in your postingdate column never change once set.

Comment: A trigger to delete then would be an 'after insert' ? is there such?

Comment: Yes, you can have an 'after insert'. Or an 'after delete' if you wanted to put the trigger on the old table instead to run an insert if an entry is deleted from it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this with a partition table. My idea is to create table which have range partition on date:

```
create table(id number primary key,name varchar,J_date date )
partition by range(J_date)(PARTITION one_mnth VALUES LESS THAN(sysdate-30)),
partition by range(J_date)(PARTITION one_mnth VALUES LESS THAN(maxvalue)));
```

then move that partition in to another table and and truncate that partition